# Change opacity for input by dropdown list choosing with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, input, opacity

How to add .css("opacity","1") to #ifedit when #custom is chosen, but at another choose it will be opacity=.5 for #ifedit?

[Here is my Fiddle](http://codepen.io/Armbull/pen/yyRxLq)

```js
$(function() {
 $('#ifedit').prop('disabled',true);
 $('#drpevent').on('change', function(){
    $('#ifedit').prop('disabled', $(this).val() !== 'custom');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the val() of the selectbox:

```
 $(function() {
     $('#ifedit').prop('disabled',true);
     $('#drpevent').on('change', function(){
        if ($('#drpevent').val() == 'custom') {
          $('#ifedit').prop('disabled',false).css('opacity','1');
        } else {
          $('#ifedit').prop('disabled',true).css('opacity','0.5');
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
   $('#ifedit').prop('disabled', true);
   $('#drpevent').on('change', function() {
     $('#ifedit').prop('disabled', $(this).val() !== 'custom');
     if ($('#drpevent').val() == 'custom') {
       $('#ifedit').css('opacity', '1');
     } else {
       $('#ifedit').css('opacity', '0.5');
     }
   });
 });
```